# how to record screen video in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, screen-recording

I am doing a guess song game app , I need to record the screen when the user is guessing and capture the device's audio output as well. I want my app to support ios8 , so "ReplayKit" is off the table, then which SDK should I use? 
I am a beginner, if there's any example code would be much more help，thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using Apple's ReplayKit, you can let your user record gameplay, or in your case, whatever the user is doing.

A link to the WWDC 2015 presentation is included [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/605/)

Use these functions to start and stop recording:

```
func startRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

        recorder.startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true) { [unowned self] (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Stop", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "stopRecording")
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

        recorder.stopRecordingWithHandler { [unowned self] (preview, error) in
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Start", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "startRecording")

            if let unwrappedPreview = preview {
                unwrappedPreview.previewControllerDelegate = self
                self.presentViewController(unwrappedPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's a good solution, thanks. But my app is also supported for ios8 , is there any other sdk I can use ?

Comment: I think you can only jailbreak :(

Comment: you could look into how this app works (http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-record-iphone-screen-video-on-ios-8.3-8.4-without-jailbreak/)

Comment: But I need a built-in record screen feature

Comment: if you mean without code, then just use quicktime. if not, just follow the example i sent you.

Comment: Is there a way to make the quality of the recorded video better using ReplayKit?

Answer (score 0):

RPScreenRecorder is kind of cool, although you could not access the video, or even access it. The only way how to do video screen capturing that I've came up with is to make a screenshots, store them in the array in Images and than to convert it to video. It's not cool from performance standpoint and it's hard to achieve 30+fps, but might work for some use cases, here's the [full manual how to do it](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/05/21/swift-how-to-record-a-screen-video-or-convert-images-to-videos/).

Comment: The link you provided for your blog is not working. I'm trying to capture a part of NSView by taking screenshots. Please let me know any solution. Regards